# WinCE - DEBUGMSG not printing the string properly

Tags: embedded, windows-ce

I'm a beginner. I'm using `WinCE 6`. In a WCE console application, I added the following code.

```
char s[5]="abcd";
DEBUGMSG(1,(TEXT("%s\r\n"),s));
```

The output I get is `ac`. I kept breakpoint and observed `s`. It showed that it contains `abcd`.

The same logic of code when I try in Win32 Console application, it works fine. I think this is something specific to WinCE.

Please guide me where I'm going wrong while printing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string may need to be 16-bit unicode characters.  Try changing the type of s from char to wchar_t.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But, Could you tell me how to identify where we have to use 16-bit unicode characters? I'm currently working with Device Emulator.

Comment: You have to use Unicode everywhere you're using OS APIs or TCHAR macros.

Comment: Thanks @ctacke. But, why is `char` not preferred in those?

Comment: WinCE (and Windows in general) is designed with internationalization of language and fonts in mind.  16-bit unicode characters are better suited for internationalization than 8-bit chars.

Comment: WinCE has almost no ASCII (8-bit char) APIs.  It uses Unicode characters, which is what the TCHAR macros expand to when UNICODE is defined.